# Unable to push a new project to github

Tags: git, github

I have created a new project locally, and trying to push it to github as follows:

```
1. run 'git init' command in myproject directory.
2. run 'git add .'
3. run git commit -m "First commit"
4. Create a repository 'MyRepository' on github site
5. Also added ssh public key at github
6. git remote add origin repository-URL
7. git push -u origin master
```

Step 7 gives me an authentication error:

> fatal: Authentication failed for XXX

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What happens when you test the ssh key? https://help.github.com/en/articles/testing-your-ssh-connection

Comment: Also, did the repo url start with `https://` or `git@`?

Comment: Have you added the ssh key to the local ssh-agent process? https://help.github.com/en/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent#adding-your-ssh-key-to-the-ssh-agent

Comment: ssh -T git@github.com..this gives me 'Hi mghildiy! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.'

Comment: Excellent. The ssh set up should be fine then. How about that repo url? Were you pushing to https:// or git@?

Comment: I first tried with https one, then with ssh one(@git). But both failed.

Comment: I did it hard way. I cloned the repository and then copied my stuff in it and pushed it.

Comment: And that worked? That’s odd. It isn’t anything to do with the key or ssh then. Well, enjoy your new github repo!

Comment: Yes that worked. Thanks for inputs anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps, it might solve your issue,
1. Open Git Bash and Change the current working directory to your local project.

2. Initialize the local directory as a Git repository.
   i.e git init
3. Add the files in your new local repository. This stages them for the first commit.
   i.e git add .

   4. Commit the files that you’ve staged in your local repository.
      i.e
      git commit -m "initial commit"
4. Copy the https url of your newly created repo
   In the Command prompt, add the URL for the remote repository where your local repository will be pushed.

i.e git remote add origin remote repository URL

Then
git remote -v

6. Push the changes in your local repository to GitHub.

i.e git push origin master

Comment: The answer is wrong - the problem is permissions. missing ssh keys or https password

Answer (score 0):

The error means that you don't have the ssh connection on your machine.

You mentioned that you have created ssh-key

> 5. Also added ssh public key at github

Looks like you did not updated your remote URL with the ssh URL

---

#### What to do?

1. First, check to see if you set up the key correctly

   ```
   ssh-keyscan github.com
   ```
2. If you get errors - continue and follow the detailed steps below.
3. if the connection is working properly update your local url:

   ```
   git remote set origin <ssh url>
   ```

---

## Creating and adding ssh key under your github account

Source: https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.15/user/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account

#### Generating ssh key

- Open Git Bash.
- Run `ssh-keygen` and follow the on-screen messages (or simply click <kbd>Enter</kbd> till it over)
- Copy the key file (the content of the public key) located in:

  ```
   ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
  ```

#### Add key to Github

- In the upper-right corner of any page, click your profile photo, then click Settings.
  [image]
- In the user settings sidebar, click SSH and GPG keys.
  [image]
- Click New SSH key or Add SSH key.
  [image]
- Paste your key into the "Key" field.
  [image]
- Click Add SSH key.
  [image]
- **change the repository url to ssh**

  ```
  git remote set origin <ssh url>
  ```